# How to select first entry of each ItemType

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

```
Items (ItemType varchar(20), Size int)
```

I have to select the first entry of each `ItemType`. For this I have used the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         Size, ItemType, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemType ORDER BY Size) AS RowNum
     FROM    
         Items) s
```

But my this is showing output with repeating `ItemType`. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `WHERE` condition to restrict to the first row for each partition:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Size, ItemType,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemType ORDER BY Size) AS RowNum
    FROM Items
) s
WHERE s.RowNum = 1
```